# Location tracking while device is moving

Tags: android, location

I am developing an application that tracks the device's location specially when it is moving. I am getting different response in Samsung and HTC device with different OS version for same API call.

Here is my code.

`private static final long HUNDERE_METERS = 100; // in Meters`
`private static final long TWO_MIN = 60000*2; // in Milliseconds`

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
criteria.setBearingAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
String provider = mlocManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TWO_MIN, HUNDERE_METERS, mlocListener);
```

'Samsung Galaxy Nexus-4.1.1' gives the location updates on every distance moved by HUNDRED_METERS (100 meters) which is fine. But in 'HTC EVO 3D PG86100-4.0.3' GPS become unavailable for 2 minutes and then become available which is causing location updates after every 2 minutes.

I modified the code as below

```
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, TWO_MIN, HUNDERE_METERS, mlocListener);
```

Now HTC start working fine and giving locations for every distance moved by 100 meters but in Samsung GPS become unavailable for every 2 minutes.

Please suggest with what argument should I call requestLocationUpdates to get location updates for distance moved by desired distance which should we work for all Android devices and OS.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Android 4.1 Jelly Bean, per the Android Location API spec the minTime and minDistance parameters were merely "hints" to the device that the app wanted to preserve energy.

OEMs could actually implement this however they wanted, which resulted in some inconsistent behavior on various Android devices.  So, prior to Android 4.1, you'll see various behavior on different devices when using the same minTime and minDistance parameters.

Included in this inconsistent behavior is a bug that affects a number of different devices where the minTime parameter is completely ignored.  See this conversation with the Android team for details:

https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/34230/

Starting in Android 4.1, the Location API spec has been tightened up and additional CtsVerifier tests have been added to enforce more consistent behavior across Android devices.

The expected behavior on Android 4.1 and above is:

"The update interval can be controlled using the minTime parameter. The elapsed time between location updates will never be less than minTime, although it can be more depending on the Location Provider implementation and the update interval requested by other applications.

...

The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider will only send your application an update when the location has changed by at least minDistance meters, AND at least minTime milliseconds have passed. However it is more difficult for location providers to save power using the minDistance parameter, so minTime should be the primary tool to conserving battery life.

...

Prior to Jellybean, the minTime parameter was only a hint, and some location provider implementations ignored it. From Jellybean and onwards it is mandatory for Android compatible devices to observe both the minTime and minDistance parameters."

From:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,long,float,android.location.LocationListener)